# Direct Proof of "If $5x^2+8$ is odd then $x$ is odd"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, parity

From my basic understanding of proofs, the best way to tackle this proof is by contrapositive which I have done but I need it to be using direct proof. Also, there is a hint in the question stating "if $x^2$ is odd then $x$ is odd".
Any additional hints are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: $n = ax+2b\,$ odd $\Rightarrow n-2b= ax\,$ odd $\Rightarrow x\,$ odd, since every divisor of an odd is odd (not even). Said modly: $\!\bmod 2\!:\ 1 \equiv ax+2b\equiv 
 ax\Rightarrow x\equiv 1\ $ (not $\,x\equiv 0).\ $ OP is case $\,a=5x,\ b=4\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$5x^2+8\equiv5x^2\equiv(5\bmod 2)x^2\equiv x^2\equiv x\mod 2.$$

Alternatively:

$$5(2n)^2+8=2(10n^2+4),\\5(2n+1)^2=2(10n^2+10n+4)+1.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't studies about parity of odd and even numbers maybe that's why I've been stuck

Answer (score 0):

Let $5x^2+8=2n+1$

Then $5x^2=2(n-4)+1$ is also odd.

Then $x^2$ also has to be odd (only multiplication of odd numbers can give an odd number), which implies that $x$ is odd (as per the hint).

Comment: I understand the logic behind you're answer but I'm kinda confused on on how you got $5x^2=2(n-4)+1$

Comment: @auxiliamus I took $8$ to RHS